# Infinite scroll not work when scroll down

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I have a code infinite scroll, but i have a problem.
Why my code work when scroll up not when scroll down?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
        if(($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) && (lastID != 0)){
     //Why work when scroll up? i want this work when scroll down
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url('berita/load_more'); ?>',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').remove();
                    $('#postList').append(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Look live demo on https://tabungamal.id/berita/infinite

Comment: It would be great if you post your code here or code pane

Comment: ok, code has been updated my brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again with this code

```
function scrollEvt(){
    var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
    if(((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) && (lastID != 0)){
        $(window).off('scroll');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'https://tabungamal.id/berita/load_more',
            data:'id='+lastID,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('.load-more').show();
            },
            success:function(html){
                $('.load-more').remove();
                $('#postList').append(html);
                $(window).scroll(scrollEvt);
            }
        });
    }


}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(scrollEvt);

});
```

Comment: I'am sorry, i want ask again. 
In my case this time the scroll did not reach the bottom, precisely above the footer the data must be loaded_more

Comment: what if i want to modify my code by using click? no longer using scroll

Comment: Just $ (window) .off ('scroll'); I don't need the source so I think you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the source.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
//Try modifying here
        if(((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) && (lastID != 0)){

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url('berita/load_more'); ?>',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').remove();
                    $('#postList').append(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's work with scroll down, but looping infinite is error, 
there is repeated content

Comment: when I use my initial code there is no repetitive content error like this

Comment: The scroll event seems to be a duplicate.